# Why in SQL Server Decimal type round up every decimal result?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this TSQL script:

```
declare @dcml decimal
declare @flt float

SELECT @dcml = 5/cast(4 AS float)
PRINT(@dcml) -- return 1

SELECT @flt = 5/cast(4 AS float)
PRINT(@flt)  -- return 1.25
```

Why in the first case the result is rounded even with a decimal container for result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default, the number of digits that are stored after the decimal point is 0, and you haven't specified a value to override this.

See [the MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

To fix:

```
declare @dcml decimal(18,5)
```

This will store 5 digits after the decimal point.

Basically you had an integer type there.

Comment: Perfect, now it's working in SQL side. But when I run my VB.net application that value is still 1 (in place of 0,61). Why? Do I need to specify precision even in my source code? How? I use SqlDbType.Decimal as type.

Comment: I can't comment on code I can't see. If you're referring to setting parameter types on command objects, then yes, you need to specify precision and scale there as well. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.scale.aspx] for more information (it holds true for the SqlClient parameter type as well).

Comment: Then see [SqlParameter.Precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.precision.aspx) and [SqlParameter.Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx). These two correspond to the 18 and 5 from my example.